# Difference between ISTQB & BBST, Which one have powerful content?

Tags: manual-testing, istqb

I know it could be an opinion-based question between two groups(ISTQB vs BBST) but I would like to say as the content is invaluable for anyone who wants to be a better tester. if as freshers want to start his/her career then which one will be more valuable from the content & skill point of view. which can help most to the candidate in the competitive world or make someone a good test tester?

Comment: When you see it from a career perspective ISTQB has more value, just go to linked in and search keyword istqb under jobs , you can find many roles but for bbst its hard to find any.

Comment: This is entirely an opinion based question.Although certifications may help to understand the terminology  a bit , it is practical exposure testing real projects which clarifies and solidifies the testing concepts in one's mind.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal I don't understand how is this opinion based when you have reference like available job roles, user experience., recruiter feedback etc  This question is important for someone who is planing to start a career in this industry.

Comment: Certification is like real estate investment, you put down your time , money and efforts , and its important to choose the right one.

Comment: If this is opinion based, then even this too https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/44703/40022. Most questions will be opinion based and the answers will be to, it is up to the author of the question to choose the best answer that is applicable to his context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be an opinion-based question, so I'll add my opinion.

I've yet to find a job description that would mention BBST, but I've found several that mentioned ISTQB among the requirements. PDHide mentioned something similar in the comment section. You can try to search on some job portals and gather more information on this. I've also been asked some questions from the exams during interviews. However, it's important to know that frequency does not automatically equal quality or usefulness or whatever. It very well could be that ISTQB is more available, therefore it's easy to want candidates to have this exam as at least some sort of proof they are serious about testing.

You can actually see the syllabus for ISTQB online: https://www.istqb.org/downloads/syllabi/foundation-level-syllabus.html That's actually all that will be tested during the exam. I still think you can learn something from it, but it's important to balance it with some context and practice.

On the other hand, BBST seems to be a bit more practical:

[image]

"Buzzwords" such as domain testing, risk-based testing, bug advocacy, testing tours, context-driver testing are highly relevant, yet ISTQB doesn't seem to mention them. It's partly just a different terminology, but that matters as well after all.

Lastly, I don't think this should a either-or question. You can sign up both for ISTQB and BBST. They will bring different values to you, and you'll most likely learn something from both. If, however, you want to focus only on being successful "in your CV", ISTQB seems to have a bigger reach.

Comment: in ISTQB domain testing is mentioned as Equivalent partition , with each partition to be considered as a domain

Comment: I would recommend to start with ISTQB and then do anything else. As it gives clear introduction to simple yet important terminologies and approaches needed in Testing domain.  It helps you during technical team discussions , sometimes words plays more role than skills when it comes to management level. Thats why we have BDD , KDD etc :D

Comment: word of caution - once you learn all these good terms and procedures you may be more frustrated at your workplace and with co-workers who don't know the terms and practices.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant true should know the audience