# Which AWS certification to pursue for a road towards becoming an SDET/test architect?

Tags: automated-testing, aws, sdet

Should I go for an AWS certified Developer associate? Since I have good programming experience related to Test automation and want to move my career as a Test architect or tools and automation software engineer?

Comment: Voting for Close because any answer will be opinion-based, for any certification or to not take any certification at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays it is more around DevOps and would recommend that you work out on the following:

- Cloud Practitioner: Best one for a starter course
- Architect Associate: Good for a QA or Test resource
- Developer Associate: Gives you good in-depth knowledge on how to manage services and link up the integrations
- Security Specialty: Once you have finished the above this one is a good course to do also.

Comment: Thank you @gagneet

Comment: How to prepare for the certification , Is it self learned ?

Comment: There are courses available for free with AWS itself. Then you can go onto places like Skillshare and Udemy, which has a sale on some of these courses. Also, try to open an AWS account and experiment on your own. You get to practically learn a lot of things which the courses might not teach. Look into any generic application using NodeJS/ReactJS and you can build it in AWS using things like FarGate, EC2, API Gateway, Lambda, etc. These will enhance your knowledge. The actual certification is available online with AWS and in Learning Centres (location on the AWS website)